# Navbar bootstrap desaparece em certo tamanho

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Sabemos que o bootstrap tem as classes visible-xs, -sm, -md, lg e hidden-xs, -sm, -md, -lg para setar quando o menu será exibido.

O menu alterna para collapse de acordo com o tamanho do navegador ou resolução do dispositivo.

Acontece que, em certo momento, nenhum dos menus aparece: nem o collapsed, nem o completo. Quando está pequeno, aparece o collapsed, que expande com o clique. Quando grande, aparece o menu normal. Porém, quando está em meio termo, fica sem menu. Como resolver isso? Preciso que o menu completo exiba em lg ou md, e que fique collapsed quando sm e xs.

Não sei se fui claro. Difícil explicar isso. rs

Comment: Posta o código do menu que tem que fica mais fácil.... Mas mesmo sem olhar pode ser que tem classe a mais ou faltando, mas isso só podemos dizer olhando código...

Comment: posta seu HTML please.

Answer (score 1):

Eu tenho assim a minha navbar e funciona perfeitamente:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="navbar-header">
  <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand">Início</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-main">
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
 </div>
 <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-main">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">           
   <li><a href="xxx.php">XXX</a></li>
   <li><a href="yyy.php">YYY</a></li>
   ...  
  </ul>     
 </div>
</div>
```

Mas se colocasses o teu código, ou um exemplo parecido seria mais fácil ver o que se passa.